# Plot CDF from Pandas series with index as x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a Pandas series that has an index and the values are the counts for each value of the index. I want to plot a CDF (preferably just the line, not the full histogram) where the x-axis represents the index.

For example, if my series is `s`, I have `s.index` as the array of values that should be represented on the x-axis and `s.values` are the counts. I have tried just doing `s.plot(cumulative = True,...)`but that puts the values on the x-axis, not the index.

Example: `s.index` yields an array of values from 0 to 1, with 0.01 increments (0.00, 0.01, 0.02, ... 1.00). `s.values` yields an array of the counts, for example (4372, 1340, 205,...), where each one corresponds to the index (0.01 has a count of 1340). I would like the x-axis to be the 0.00, 0.01,... and the y-axis goes from 0 to 1 as the cumulative distribution based on the counts.

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected output

Comment: @RajatMishra Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

Using seaborn package, you can achieve that:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import seaborn as sns
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 x = np.arange(0,.1,0.01)
 df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1340,1200,1300,1150,1421,1175,1232,1432,1123,1231]},index=x)
 df
       value
0.00   1340
0.01   1200
0.02   1300
0.03   1150
0.04   1421
0.05   1175
0.06   1232
0.07   1432
0.08   1123
0.09   1231
sns.distplot(df.index, rug=True, hist=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]